# test whether shapes were actually drawn on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Canvas Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406864/html-canvas-unit-testing)

I want to write a unit test (using Jasmine) to determine whether a function correctly drew some lines on an HTML5 canvas. Here is a simplified version of the code under test:

```js
var plotter = {};
plotter.draw = function(input) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.moveTo(input.startX, input.startY);
    context.lineTo(input.endX, input.endY);
    context.stroke();
    return canvas;
};
```

How can I inspect the canvas to make sure the draw function worked correctly? Is it possible? If not, would it be better to return some metadata along with the canvas, and then inspect the metadata?