# HTML5 Canvas drawImage return

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Is there anyway to get this methods return? Just to check if it was executed or not?

```
context.drawImage(video,0,0,100,200);
```

Thannks

Answer (score 1):

The method returns `void` (see [w3 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/)):

```
  // drawing images
  void drawImage((HTMLImageElement or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLVideoElement) image, unrestricted double dx, unrestricted double dy);
```

There are some good suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406864/html-canvas-unit-testing) on how to unit test `canvas` code.